# Unable to create new s3 bucket in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm attempting to create a new s3 bucket and getting a conflict though I know the bucket name is new, unique, and has been many hours (8+) since that name was in use. Details attached. I've even tried with a new name that I know was never a bucket in my account (and likely never a bucket).

The name in the logs below is made up and not the one I was using, which was unique and namespaced to my domain.

If I use the aws s3 cli to make the bucket (i.e. `aws s3 mb s3://{same-bucket-name} --region us-east-2`) where `{same-bucket-name}` is the name of the bucket I want to create, it works fine.

```sh
2019-07-07T00:12:19.463-0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.18.0_x4: 2019/07/07 00:12:19 [DEBUG] Trying to create new S3 bucket: "my-unique-s3-bucket-name"
2019-07-07T00:12:19.464-0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.18.0_x4: 2019/07/07 00:12:19 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Request s3/CreateBucket Details:
2019-07-07T00:12:19.464-0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.18.0_x4: ---[ REQUEST POST-SIGN ]-----------------------------
2019-07-07T00:12:19.464-0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.18.0_x4: PUT /my-unique-s3-bucket-name HTTP/1.1
2019-07-07T00:12:19.464-0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.18.0_x4: Host: s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
2019-07-07T00:12:19.464-0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.18.0_x4: User-Agent: aws-sdk-go/1.20.12 (go1.12.5; darwin; amd64) APN/1.0 HashiCorp/1.0 Terraform/0.12.2
2019-07-07T00:12:19.464-0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.18.0_x4: Content-Length: 153
2019-07-07T00:12:19.464-0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.18.0_x4: Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=MYCREDS/20190707/us-east-2/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-length;host;x-amz-acl;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=b5acd2dbcaf09eda51b4ea8448f1991d26c8eb8249a85e7ac28044864df377b9
2019-07-07T00:12:19.464-0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.18.0_x4: X-Amz-Acl: public-read
2019-07-07T00:12:19.464-0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.18.0_x4: X-Amz-Content-Sha256: 70cae86320841ea73b0bdc759f99920c7caa405e61af2742575750c6586272c9
2019-07-07T00:12:19.464-0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.18.0_x4: X-Amz-Date: 20190707T041219Z
2019-07-07T00:12:19.464-0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.18.0_x4: Accept-Encoding: gzip
2019-07-07T00:12:19.464-0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.18.0_x4:
2019-07-07T00:12:19.464-0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.18.0_x4: <CreateBucketConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/"><LocationConstraint>us-east-2</LocationConstraint></CreateBucketConfiguration>
2019-07-07T00:12:19.464-0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.18.0_x4: -----------------------------------------------------
2019-07-07T00:12:19.697-0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.18.0_x4: 2019/07/07 00:12:19 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Response s3/CreateBucket Details:
2019-07-07T00:12:19.697-0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.18.0_x4: ---[ RESPONSE ]--------------------------------------
2019-07-07T00:12:19.697-0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.18.0_x4: HTTP/1.1 409 Conflict
2019-07-07T00:12:19.697-0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.18.0_x4: Connection: close
2019-07-07T00:12:19.697-0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.18.0_x4: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
2019-07-07T00:12:19.697-0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.18.0_x4: Content-Type: application/xml
2019-07-07T00:12:19.697-0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.18.0_x4: Date: Sun, 07 Jul 2019 04:12:19 GMT
2019-07-07T00:12:19.697-0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.18.0_x4: Server: AmazonS3
2019-07-07T00:12:19.697-0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.18.0_x4: X-Amz-Id-2: v5M1x31BcVCS4DLIgqmCR4KRHipO3ZRbTSXF1PCS9+q9nyT8O5/3s04Z22o8t4x8JZ0HF9HWkO4=
2019-07-07T00:12:19.697-0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.18.0_x4: X-Amz-Request-Id: 835B636D828335A1
2019-07-07T00:12:19.697-0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.18.0_x4:
2019-07-07T00:12:19.697-0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.18.0_x4:
2019-07-07T00:12:19.698-0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.18.0_x4: -----------------------------------------------------
2019-07-07T00:12:19.698-0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.18.0_x4: 2019/07/07 00:12:19 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
2019-07-07T00:12:19.698-0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.18.0_x4: <Error><Code>OperationAborted</Code><Message>A conflicting conditional operation is currently in progress against this resource. Please try again.</Message><RequestId>835B636D828335A1</RequestId><HostId>v5M1x31BcVCS4DLIgqmCR4KRHipO3ZRbTSXF1PCS9+q9nyT8O5/3s04Z22o8t4x8JZ0HF9HWkO4=</HostId></Error>
2019-07-07T00:12:19.698-0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.18.0_x4: 2019/07/07 00:12:19 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Validate Response s3/CreateBucket failed, attempt 0/25, error OperationAborted: A conflicting conditional operation is currently in progress against this resource. Please try again.
2019-07-07T00:12:19.698-0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.18.0_x4:  status code: 409, request id: 835B636D828335A1, host id: v5M1x31BcVCS4DLIgqmCR4KRHipO3ZRbTSXF1PCS9+q9nyT8O5/3s04Z22o8t4x8JZ0HF9HWkO4=
2019-07-07T00:12:19.698-0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.18.0_x4: 2019/07/07 00:12:19 [WARN] Got an error while trying to create S3 bucket my-unique-s3-bucket-name: OperationAborted: A conflicting conditional operation is currently in progress against this resource. Please try again.
2019-07-07T00:12:19.698-0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.18.0_x4:  status code: 409, request id: 835B636D828335A1, host id: v5M1x31BcVCS4DLIgqmCR4KRHipO3ZRbTSXF1PCS9+q9nyT8O5/3s04Z22o8t4x8JZ0HF9HWkO4=
2019-07-07T00:12:19.698-0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.18.0_x4: 2019/07/07 00:12:19 [TRACE] Waiting 10s before next try
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the bucket did previously exist then there is an indeterminate amount of time before that bucket name is released.

Unfortunately the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/delete-bucket.html) aren't very specific here:

> **Important**
>
> If you want to continue to use the same bucket name, don't delete the
> bucket. We recommend that you empty the bucket and keep it. After a
> bucket is deleted, the name becomes available to reuse, but the name
> might not be available for you to reuse for various reasons. For
> example, it might take some time before the name can be reused, and
> some other account could create a bucket with that name before you do.

You can talk to AWS support to confirm what's happening (and check that another AWS account doesn't have the bucket) but ultimately you just need to wait. If the S3 bucket matches a domain name that you control and you intend to use it for website hosting and someone else already has that S3 bucket then there is a process for getting that bucket name back to you, just as there is with CloudFront CNAMEs which are also globally unique.

You should also be able to check if the bucket name is available by running [the following command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/head-bucket.html):

```
aws s3api head-bucket --bucket [bucket name]
```

Ages back when we briefly tried deleting S3 buckets in test environments over night (along with everything else) we would occasionally see this error for over 48 hours while sometimes the bucket name was available again within a few hours. Unfortunately, AWS provide no guarantees here.

Comment: Yes, oddly `head-bucket` return 404 and `mb` works fine when I create the bucket that terraform cannot. Not sure what's up.